Unable to Retrieve Comments for a Translation Using Lokalise API
I am trying to retrieve comments associated with a specific translation in my Lokalise project using the Lokalise API. However, I keep encountering issues with the API endpoint and parameters. Here is the request I have tried:
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.lokalise.com/api2/projects/{projectId}/translations/{translationId}/comments' \
  -H 'x-api-token: {apiKey}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

This just returns:
{
   'message': 'Invalid `project_id` parameter', 
   'code': 400
}

However when I execute:
curl -X GET \
  'https://api.lokalise.com/api2/projects/{projectId}/translations/{translationId}' \
  -H 'x-api-token: {apiKey}' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json'

I get a valid response with all the data I expect.
Web Inter
When I use the web interface, I am able to view the comment. The request which is sent from the client is:
curl -X GET \
  'https://app.lokalise.com/collaboration/projects/{projectId}/translations/{translationId}'

This returns the expected comment with all its data.
How can I correctly retrieve the comments for a translation using the Lokalise API? Any help would be appreciated.
